# My audio files won't play anymore? how to fix?

Tags: html

```
<embed name="audioforwebsite" src="audiofile1.mp3" type="audio/mp3"
 autostart="false" Hidden="true" ></embed>
<audio loop autoplay>
  <source src="audiofile1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
```

I use this code and it used to work on my website. However for some reason, it doesn't work anymore.
(i use chrome to play it)

i'm very new to coding and i've looked around the internet for the past hour, but none of the advice seem to work.

my objective is to create an audio file that auto plays when you get into the website, it loops, and it cant be seen in the form of a play/pause button thingy.

help me please.

if you dont know how to fix it, please tell me how to make a new one that you know works using HTML chrome. Thanks.

Comment: Click F12, go to network, reload the page and see if you see the mp3 files

Comment: Does your browser's developer console show any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Auto Play in Chrome ist disabled for security reasons. The user has to click in your page or do anything.

Comment: how can i make it then?

Comment: If your files are loaded and it doesn't play it is not possible. Only if the user startet Chrome with chrome.exe --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required.